# What border is this?

Tags: css

[image: Need to get rid of this white border]

I am trying to get rid of this white border around the input box when it is in focus (not there unless the input is clicked on). I thought it would have been `:focus`, but it is not and I cannot find anything on the web.

Comment: You can remove it with the `:focus` sub-selector

Comment: It's an css outline

Comment: there’s also `:focus-visible`, and that border specifically is Chrome’s current `outline`, not `border` btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've tried this without success:

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

This might work for you:

```
input:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
```

In case none of the above helped, this should solve your problem:

```
input:focus {
    outline:none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```